# Strength of strong nuclear force vs distance?

Tags: forces, nuclear-physics, strong-force

Is there at least an approximation of the decrease in strong nuclear attraction vs distance from the center of the nucleus?

Comment: The force actually increases up to a distance because of the strange way quarks + gluons form chains.

Comment: Just to add to the above comment. For distances larger than the nuclear scale, the potential is modelled by the Yukawa potential.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the article in [wikipedia on nuclear force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force).

Various models exist that describe the behavior of nuclear forces, which are the result of a spill over of the strong force, the force that exists within the proton and the neutron.

From the link

[image: force between nucleons]

> Force (in units of 10,000 N) between two nucleons that experience the nuclear force, as a function of distance. In the graph that falls below the horizontal axis, the spins of the particles (which must be different, such as a neutron and proton) are aligned, and they become bound with a negative "binding energy," which becomes maximal at a distance a little more than 1 fermi (Fm) at the minimum of the region shown. Particles much closer than this optimal distance experience a repulsive force. Particles farther than the distance of highest attractive force still experience a smaller attractive potential (Yukawa potential), but it falls at an exponential function of distance.

Repulsive forces exist because of charge distributions ( quarks within the nucleons are charged)  and the Pauli exclusion principle.

More complicated nuclei are a many body problem and models exist that fit the measurements and predict behaviors, like [the shell model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model), or the [liquid drop model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula).